# How to auto-scroll to a selected horizontal element not in view, within a container, when the page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a demo horizontal navigation system here: http://benfrain.com/playground/scroller.html

It works great but if you arrive on the page with while the default selected item is, say, 'Wardrobes', this item is going to be out of sight for most smaller screens.

Is there a way to have the horizontal nav bar auto scroll, after page load, if the default active item is currently out of view? I am not good enough at JS to apply the code logic already in place to make this happen, yet, but I think it's very close.

Thanks in advance!!

EDIT:

In reply the solution by @cantuket below, I would like to clarify that all these links will be directing users to different pages, not somewhere else on the same page. Visitors and other pages will no utilize hashtag URL extensions. With that in mind, I do not think the hashtag solution solve the issue, but it's so close! I must be brain-dead tired at this point because I can't seem to figure out the correct way to utilize the direction @cantuket was going in, but rather than using hashtags, implement IDs within each link tags, and then put the active, matching ID into a the body tag as a Class.

```
// Added class in the body tag which would match the ID of the link tag that should be active
<body class="hpn-7"> 
...
// Added id in the link tag
    <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link" aria-selected="true" id="hpn-7">Wardrobe</a>
...
// new JS
    var ids, matches = document.body.className.match(/(^|\s)hpn-(\d+)(\s|$)/);
    if (matches) {
        // found the id
        ids = matches[0];

        var $elem = ids;
        moveIndicator($elem[0], colours[$links.index($elem)])  
        var $navPosition = $('#pnProductNav').scrollLeft(),
        $elemPosition = $elem.offset().left;

        $("#pnProductNav").animate({scrollLeft: $navPosition + $elemPosition}, 800);
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First,

- Added IDs to all the nav links.
- Added a single Class to the body tag, matching one of the nav link IDs. This will identify the active link.
- Fixed the code snippet I included into my question with simplified jQuery.

UPDATED new JS

```
// Scroll if selected item is not in view when the page loads but not after or during.

// First, find and get body class name that starts with "hpn-"

var ids, matches = document.body.className.match(/(^|\s)hpn-(\d+)(\s|$)/);
if (matches) {

    // found the id so define it
    ids = matches[0];

    // Get position of the nav bar and the position of the link with the matching ID
    var navPosition = $('#pnProductNav').scrollLeft(),
        elemPosition = $('#' + ids).offset().left;

    // Add the two together to get your scroll distance and animate    
    $("#pnProductNav").animate({scrollLeft: navPosition + elemPosition}, 800);

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sstracy/goe8j3sv/12/

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is pretty broad so I it would be best for you to look over the solution and ask questions, rather than me explaining everything, but here is a full solution...

```js
    if (window.location.hash) {
            var hash = window.location.hash.replace('#',""),
                $links = $('#pnProductNavContents > a');
                linksAndIds = (function(){
                    var res = [];
                    $links.each(function(){
                        var elem  = $(this),
                            id = elem.text().toLocaleLowerCase().split(' ').join('-').replace('&','and');    
                        res.push({elem, id})
                    })
                    return res;
                })();

            var validHash = linksAndIds.find(({id})=> hash === id);
            
            if (validHash) {
                var $elem = $(validHash.elem);

                moveIndicator($elem[0], colours[$links.index($elem)])

                var navPosition = $('#pnProductNav').scrollLeft(),
                    elemPosition = $elem.offset().left;

                $("#pnProductNav").animate({scrollLeft: navPosition + elemPosition}, 800);
            }
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I added jQuery to the project because...

1. I'm lazy
2. At your level of experience I think using jQuery is the best way to get started interacting with the DOM.

You can now enter any of these 'hashes' at the end of your URL and it will select and scroll to the right element...

```
var hashList = [
"chairs",
"tables",
"cookware",
"beds",
"desks",
"flooring",
"lighting",
"mattresses",
"solar-panels",
"bookcases",
"mirrors",
"rugs",
"curtains-and-blinds",
"frames-and-pictures",
"wardrobes",
"storage",
"decoration",
"appliances",
"racks",
"worktops"
];
```

Query them like this...

`http://benfrain.com/playground/scroller.html#frames-and-pictures`

Full working example here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/so-dev-projects/dev.html#frames-and-pictures